# xCode 8, EXC_BAD_ACCESS RSA Encryption

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption

I'm working on RSA encryption for my app. However, I'm getting the below error:

[image]

RSAPlugin.m:

```
- (void) encryptRSA:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{

    NSString *plainTextString = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *publicKey = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    
    _rsaPub = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", publicKey];
    NSLog(@"%@", plainTextString);
    NSLog(@"%@", publicKey);
    
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = nil;
    
    NSString *EncryptedTextString = [RSAPlugin encryptRSAWithSecKeyRef:plainTextString key:[RSAPlugin addPublicKey:publicKey]];
    if( EncryptedTextString != nil ){
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:EncryptedTextString];
    }else{
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"ERROR"];
    }
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}


+(NSString *)encryptRSAWithSecKeyRef:(NSString *)plainTextString key:(SecKeyRef)publicKey {
     NSLog(@"%@", plainTextString);
     NSLog(@"%@", publicKey);
    size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);
    uint8_t *nonce = (uint8_t *)[plainTextString UTF8String];
    SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey,
                  kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                  nonce,
                  strlen( (char*)nonce ),
                  &cipherBuffer[0],
                  &cipherBufferSize);
    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
    NSString *base64String = [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    return base64String;
}


+ (SecKeyRef)addPublicKey:(NSString *)key{
    // This will be base64 encoded, decode it.
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:key options:0];
    data = [self stripPublicKeyHeader:data];
    if(!data){
        return nil;
    }
    
    //a tag to read/write keychain storage
    NSString *tag = @"RSAUtil_PubKey";
    NSData *d_tag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[tag UTF8String] length:[tag length]];
    
    // Delete any old lingering key with the same tag
    NSMutableDictionary *publicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [publicKey setObject:d_tag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey);
    
    // Add persistent version of the key to system keychain
    [publicKey setObject:data forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic forKey:(__bridge id)
     kSecAttrKeyClass];
    [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)
     kSecReturnPersistentRef];
    
    CFTypeRef persistKey = nil;
    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey, &persistKey);
    if (persistKey != nil){
        CFRelease(persistKey);
    }
    if ((status != noErr) && (status != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];
    [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];
    [publicKey setObject:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    
    
    // Now fetch the SecKeyRef version of the key
    SecKeyRef keyRef = nil;
    OSStatus status1 = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);
    if(status1 != noErr){
        return nil;
    }
    return keyRef;
}
```

I have printed the values that is coming to my `encryptRSA` and the one being send to `encryptRSAWithSecKeyRef` and the publicKey value is coming as NULL to `encryptRSAWithSecKeyRef` even through I see the value in the encryptRSA.

Logs:

**encryptRSA:**

```
2017-03-09 12:59:13.195 ManulifeBankMobile[38545:352120] Text: 123456
2017-03-09 12:59:13.195 ManulifeBankMobile[38545:352120] PublicKey : "MI************"
```

**encryptRSAWithSecKeyRef:**

```
2017-03-09 12:59:13.195 ManulifeBankMobile[38545:352120] Text: 123456
2017-03-09 12:59:13.196 ManulifeBankMobile[38545:352120] PublicKey : (null)
```

Not sure why I'm losing my publicKey value when I pass it to  encryptRSAWithSecKeyRef

xCode version 8.2.1

Comment: What does `AddPublicKey` do?

Comment: Sorry, missed to add it. Code is update now.